# Returning the value of a buffer variable

Tags: local-variables

Is this a good way to return the value of a buffer variable

```
  (if (local-variable-p variable buffer)
      (buffer-local-value variable buffer)
    (default-value variable))
```

Comment: `buffer-local-value` takes care of returning the default value if the variable has no buffer-local value. I suspect an X-Y problem, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to know whether the default value is being used or whether the buffer-local-value was set.  And report what the values are.

Comment: What's one to do to know whether a variable has a buffer-local binding in buffer ?  And report what is what.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to know whether a variable has a buffer-local binding in buffer is to use `C-h v`, the default keybinding for the function `describe-variable`.

It will do exactly what are asking for: it will tell you whether the variable has a buffer-local binding, what that local value is, and what the global value is.